# create visitor unique ID?

Tags: php, javascript

I plan to create visitor unique ID and named as log file, as existing now I use the IP visitor as log file name i.e. logs/127.0.0.1.php but I think this is not **enough** because some visitor using share an IP address for PC's.

The visitor log file itself as setting place of configuration of visitors itself, so I plan to add another unique ID to identify each different visitor so let's say the log file:
logs/127.0.0.0.1-t3451dq.php, -t3451dq as unique ID
so as long as visitor browsing on my website the unique log file as setting configuration for each user (because I use plain text)

Currently I use:

```
<?
$filename = "./logs/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".php" ; //out put logs/127.0.0.1.php
$data stripcslashes($data);
// each Visitor configuration here...
// bla...bla...

/* Writing file configurations */
    $buat = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fwrite($buat, "$data");
    fclose($buat);
?>
```

so I need $filename add the $unique ID as name of their log file. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to tell that in my site doesn't need resitered as a member... the unique visitor log file mean available for anonymous user. but how to identification unknown ip address and give the unique id?

Comment: Ever thought of just using cookies if you only need to store user specific configuration?

Comment: Yes, i think using cookies that possible way...

Answer (score 9):

Try [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

You can store this unique ID in the users session or in a cookie.

Example (not tested)

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uniqueID']))
{
    $_SESSION['uniqueID'] = uniqid();
}
$filename = "./logs/".$_SESSION['uniqueID'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".php" ;
```

Using a session will mean that if the same user closes their browser (or the session expires) they will get a new ID, which may or may not be what you want.

If you want a more persistent tracker then you may be better using cookies, and store the ID in the cookie (create a new ID if no cookie exists).

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['uniqueID']))
{
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;//however long you want
    setcookie('uniqueID', uniqid(), $expire);
}
$filename = "./logs/".$_COOKIE['uniqueID'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".php" ;
```

If you cannot use cookies/session then you may need to pass around the ID in your URL query string e.g. mypage.php?id=35dfgdfg3434

Comment: Thank You very much...
I was read your given url link above, but there are many example and i very newbie php code so i confuse which one more suitable to fix my case, maybe some one here can give me the clear example code so i get the solution for my site visitor unique id as log file name, thank you again

Comment: Nice input, I Was try both of your example code but i face some trouble, that it not auto creating log file anymore
Warning: fopen(./logs/4b1e7d0f88597127.0.0.1.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\games\inc\iplog.conf.php on line 35
Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\games\inc\iplog.conf.php on line 36
why?

Comment: Not sure, try removing the './logs/' prefix and work your way up from there.

Comment: Why don’t you use the session ID?

Answer (score 0):

Create something out of his IP and the first time he enters the page. That should be unique.

Comment: of course you are, but as I said before, using IP address only its not close enough, because many users also using share ip for many visitors, so using session id or cookies that can be make sure unique

Comment: that why I said make something out of the IP *AND* the first time he enters the page. It is very unlikely to have two users from the same ip entering a page on the same millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple options : [uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) or as you're creating a file [tempnam](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Tempnam example :

```
function log($string, $userIP = null, $filename = null){
  // Check if filename exists
  if(!file_exists(LOG_PATH.$filename)){
    $filename = tempname(LOG_PATH, $userIP.' - ');
    if(!$filename){
      return false;
    }
  }
  // write log into file
  $file = file_put_contents($filename, $string);
  if($file === false || $file != strlen($string)){
    return false;
  }
  return $filename
}
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, but sorry do u have some experienced example using uniqid and tempnam?

Comment: I tried using tempname, i see the result is tempname ussually regenerate the name of log file, not same in every you made click and refresh the site... as you see my comment below i tried using session id and also cookies but i found problems when i call from another file using include or require

Answer (score 0):

using log files for this type of use is unnecessary, it's alot easier to just shunt this type of data to a database. If it's just temporary data then use Cookies and/or Sessions

Comment: ok, Thank you..
but when using cookies and/or sessions id as log temp file as user config the requested temp log never complete. i.e.
i put this code in another page 
$filelog1 = "./logs/".$_COOKIE['uniqueID']."_".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".php" ;
$filelog2 = "./l0g5/default.php"; 
 if(file_exists($filelog1)){
        require_once $filelog1;
    }else{
        require_once $filelog2;
    }

echo "$filelog1 , $filelog2"; // test

browser responses said:
The site is redirecting the request in a way that will never complete. what this problem?